# Put background color css for particular cms page

Tags: magento-1.9, css, cms-pages

I want to ***add background color*** for this cms page
[image: I want to add background color for this cms page]

Answer (score 0):

***add css***

```
.cms-home .main-container{background-color: #06466C;}
```

***.cms-home replace your page (body class) name class***

Answer (score 0):

***Use Current Page Parent Class.***

Every CMS page has unique Class name so you can use this name to apply different background color of different page.

here some CMS page class name are list here

> **Home Page :** .cms-home.cms-index-index

> **Product 
>   List Page :** .catalog-category-view

> **Product View Page :** .catalog-product-view

> **Shoping Cart Page :** .checkout-cart-index

> **Checkout Page :** .checkout-index-index

> **Checkout Success Page :** .checkout-onepage-success

> **Contact Us Page :** .contact-index-index

> **Popular Search Page :** .search-term-popular

> **Order and Return Page ( Guest ) :** .sales-guest-form

> **Advance Search Page :** .catalogsearch-advanced-index

> **Privacy and Policy Page :** .cms-privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode

> **Create Account Page :** .customer-account-create

> **Customer Login Page :** .customer-account-login

> **Customer My Account Page :** .account.customer-account-index

> **Customer My Orders Page :** .account.sales-order-history

> **Customer My Downloadable Product Page :** .account.downloadable-customer-products

> **Customer My Wishlist Page :** .account.wishlist-index-index

> **Customer Address Book Page :** .account.customer-address-form

> **Customer Account Edit Page :** .account.customer-account-edit

> **Store Payment Methods Page :** .account.vault-cards-listaction

> **Customer Account Edit Page :** .account.paypal-billing_agreement-index

> **My Product Review Page :** .account.review-customer-index

> **Customer Newsletter Subscription Page :** .account.newsletter-manage-index

> **Cookie Page :** .cms-enable-cookies

> **Customer Service Page :** .cms-customer-service

> **404 Page :** .cms-no-route

If you add Custome page Then see in page body tag, here you will see your unique class name
[image]

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: it's very useful for change color according to different page. Thanks @Msquare